# Xidel print the original url

Tags: xidel

I am trying to extract url from a webpage and follow them and I am skipping the 4XX and 5XX.My question is Is it possible to print the URL of the request that is returning 200 using xidel

```
xidel -s --error-handling=4xx=skip,5xx=skip "URL" -e "PRINT URL"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*'https://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel_readme.txt':*

> ```
> Xidel also defines the following global default variables:
>
>    $raw         Unparsed input text
>    $url         Url the input was retrieved from (past redirect)
>    $host, $path Respective part of the url
>    $json        Parsed JSON input, if it was JSON
>    $headers     All HTTP headers, including status code
> ```

So, you're looking for `-e "$url"`.

Comment: I tried that, but I am getting this error `Error No value for option extract given (when reading argument: extract)`

Comment: Did that work for you?

Comment: What's your exact command?

Comment: `xidel -s --error-handling=4xx=skip,5xx=skip "https://google.com" -e "$url"`

Comment: You're on Linux, aren't you? In that case use single quotes (`-e '$url'`). Double quotes (`-e "$url"`) are for Windows users. Or if you insist, `-e "\$url"` should work as well, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: That was it. Double quotes is the problem